# 6 A, 30 VDC relay as substitute for a 5 A, 30 VDC relay

Tags: current, relay, specifications, substitution

May I confirm on this forum if a 6 A, 30 VDC relay can be used as a substitute for a 5 A, 30 VDC relay? They have the same number of pins as well as holding coils orientation.

I purchased a relay as a spare. I tried the use a relay with a 6 A rating, however, the unit was not responding. So, I put back the old one with the 5 A rating.

May I ask if that 1 A would make a difference?

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference. If you want a proper answer, then please link the two datasheets.

Comment: Assuming those are contact ratings rather than solenoid, I see no obstacle: please include *both* specifications. (Socketed relays?)

Comment: The 5A and 6A ratings are for the contactor part, so using a higher rating is OK. However if its not working, then its most likely because the COIL rating is different. For example - maybe your 5A relay has a 5v coil whereas the 6A relay has a 12v one. Then it won't work. So you need to check that out.

Comment: Fed, please note that this is _not_ a forum. It is a Q&A. The difference is that a forum is conversational while a Q&A is focused on asking a narrow, objectively-answerable question and garnering answers which can be voted on according to their accuracy and quality.